# AttributeError when trying to use tkFont

Tags: python, fonts, tkinter, tk-toolkit, attributeerror

When I run this code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFont

class Statify():

    def __init__(self):

        ### Broken
        self.titleFont = tkFont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=24, weight='bold')
        self.option_add(*Label*font, self.titleFont)
        ###

        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.withdraw()
        self.main = Toplevel(self.root)
        self.main.title('')
        self.main_header = Frame(self.main)
        self.main_footer = Frame(self.main)
        self.main_title = Label(self.main_header, text='Statify Me v1.0 (WIP)')
        self.main_exit = Button(self.main_footer, text='Quit', command=quit)
        self.main_header.pack()
        self.main_footer.pack()
        self.main_title.pack()
        self.main_exit.pack()
        mainloop()

statify = Statify()
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Statify.py", line 23, in <module>
    statify = Statify()
  File "Statify.py", line 7, in __init__
    self.titleFont = tkFont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=24, weight='bold')
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/tkFont.py", line 88, in __init__
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

From what I've read, this should work, and using an option file instead doesn't make a difference.

Python version 2.7.2
Tkinter verion 8.5

Comment: Is this the entire code ?

Comment: I quickly paraphrased the broken portion of a much larger application, and in doing so introduced some syntactical errors (some of which you edited - cheers!). Brionius' answer worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the [docs for tkFont](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/stdlib/tkFont.Font-class.html), you'll see that the problem is that `tkFont.Font` requires a `root` argument - i.e. a parent widget.  Fix this by moving the call to `tkFont.Font` below where you create the root window, then add `self.root` as a keyword argument, like so:

```
self.root = Tk()
self.titleFont = tkFont.Font(root=self.root, family='Helvetica', size=24, weight='bold')
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You haven't gotten to this bug yet, but there are problems with the next line - I think you meant to write `self.root.option_add` rather than `self.option_add`, and I don't know what you're trying to do with the `*Label*font` business.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the issue, and catching the problem I would've noticed next. I was attempting to specify font styles to use for all widgets of a certain type - in this code using Label as an example. But I intend to use an option file to do this for the whole application. Thanks for your help!